# Counting occurrences of specific values in several NSDictionnary within Info.plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, count, plist

I have a .plist file that I use in my application for storing data, and I retrieve all the stuff in a dictionary.

Here's what the plist looks like :

```
(
    {
    firstName = "18:43";
    imageFilePath = "exclamation.png";//     <--- THIS is what I want to track.
    lastName = "25/02/2010";
    lieu = "Class 045";
    prof = "Mr. Maths";
    publicationYear = 12;
    title = "Mathematics";
},
    {
    firstName = "16:43";
    imageFilePath = "accept.png";//          <--- NOT this
    lastName = "01/01/2011";
    lieu = "Class 045";
    prof = "Mr. Maths";
    publicationYear = 12;
    title = "Mathematics";
},
    {
    firstName = "16:43";
    imageFilePath = "exclamation.png";//     <--- THIS
    lastName = "25/02/2011";
    lieu = "Class 045";
    prof = "Mr. Maths";
    publicationYear = 12;
    title = "Mathematics";
}
)
```

*and so on...*

What I just want to do is to have an *int* (or *NSNumber*, or *NSInteger*, I don't really care) that is the value of how many occurrences of "*exclamation.png*" there are in my plist. (in the example above, that would be '2')
(this number is then going to be the App's badgeNumber)

I tried a lot of different things (including converting the plist to a string and searching, but that went badly) but I couldn't make any of them work...

Thanks for your ideas !

EDIT :

This is how I load the plist :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
[_listController save];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Books.plist"];

// The code here....    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Untested; probably compiles]

```
NSArray *dicts = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"my.plist"];
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (NSDictionary *dict in dicts) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"imageFilePath"] isEqualToString:@"exclamation.png"]) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[***Ignore:*** Predicates are only faster within Core Data -- techzen]

<strike>Here's a neater and faster way to do this:</strike>

```
NSArray *fromPlist=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"my.plist"];
NSPredicate *exPred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageFilePath==%@",@"exclamation.png"];
// NSNumber *exclamationCount=[[fromPlist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:exPred].@count];
NSNumber *exclamationCount=[[[fromPlist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:exPred] valueForKey:@"@count"]];
```

The last line says: tell array fromPlist to return another array composed of objects that match the predicate test. Then take the count of the returned array.

This is much faster (10>) than a loop especially for large arrays. Even better, your predicate can be arbitrarily complex i.e. you can test multiple attributes in many different ways in each predicate. You can also save the predicates and reuse them even if they contain variables.

The combination of key-value coding, collection operators e.g. @count, and predicates is enormously powerful. Learning to use them well opens up huge improvements in speed, reliability and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that and let you know how it goes ... I will see if I can get a noticeable speed enhancement for the stuff I use :P  EDIT : you meant "filteredArrayUsingPredicate:exPred" ?

Comment: I assume you meant `valueForKey:@"@count"]` rather than `.@count`. But this is going to be dramatically slower than the loop, particularly for large counts. For non-Core Data objects, NSPredicate is slower than simple comparisons. This is the cost of its flexibility. (Core Data is special. NSPredicate is often much faster there because it can avoid faulting among other things.) The above code also creates an expensive, unneeded temporary array by `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`. Can you give a code example with timings that shows for this problem NSPredicate is faster?

Comment: Well, I tested both solutions and they work. But here I have no idea about the speed differences, it would be interesting to test here. Thanks again to you two !

Comment: @Rob Napier -- thanks for catching the typo. I have made that several times in the last few weeks. I will correct. As for the speed, I will test but my reading of the Apple documentation says that it should be faster for large arrays. The returned array is not that expensive since it is just a list of retained addresses.

Comment: @Rob Napier-- you are correct. My testing shows that the loop is four times faster than the predicate for a large array with only one match.

Comment: Thanks for the speed tests. Definitely useful !